# pandoc.exe: Unknown writer: markdown (when called from Java)

Tags: java, pandoc, processbuilder

I put pandoc on a Windows network drive. The following call succeeds in the command line:

```
P:\Maven\pandoc\pandoc-1.19.2.1-windows\pandoc.exe -t markdown C:\devel\ContiMars2\workspace\compareABM\docs\release-notes-utf8.html
```

but when starting it from Java using ProcessBuilder,

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
command.add("P:\\Maven\\pandoc\\pandoc-1.19.2.1-windows\\pandoc.exe");
command.add("-t markdown");
command.add("C:\devel\ContiMars2\workspace\compareABM\docs\release-notes-utf8.html");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

I get:

```
pandoc.exe: Unknown writer:  markdown
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the usual problem with spaces in commands that are given to `ProcessBuilder`. If you write `--to=markdown` instead of `-t markdown`, everything is fine.